# Как сделать условие при НЕ выполнении предустановленного?

Tags: python-3.x

```
data = 'aaaaabbbbccccaaa'
c = 0
n = 0


while data[n] == data[n + 1]:
    c += 1
    n += 1
    # ТУТ МНЕ НУЖНО КАКОЕ-ТО УСЛОВИЕ ДЛЯ ОБНУЛЕНИЯ ПЕРЕМЕННЫХ И УСТАНОВКИ 
    НОВОЙ СТРОКИ DATA
"""
#ЕСЛИ ЦИКЛ ПЕРЕСТАЕТ ВЫПОЛНЯТЬСЯ, НУЖНО ЗАМЕНИТЬ СТАРУЮ СТРОКУ DATA НА НОВУЮ 
И ОБНУЛИТЬ ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ:

data = data[n] + str(c) + data[n+1:]
n = 0
с=0

"""
```

Как написать условие которое будет запускаться после того как цикл перестанет работать, чтобы сделать новую строку, обнулить переменные и прогнать это еще раз через while? Как я понял нужно что-то вроде if 0, false?

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    data = 'aaaaabbbbccccaaa'
    c = 0
    n = 0
    while data[n] == data[n + 1]:
        c += 1
        n += 1
    data = data[n] + str(c) + data[n+1:]
    n = 0
    с = 0
```